Testing a Homemade Transimpendence Amplifier
I am trying to build a homemade transimpendence amplifier to measure the signal in a Reverse-Biased photodiode as a laser pulse illuminates it, but am having trouble getting it to actually operate, and I'm not sure if it's a problem with the design or an issue with my testing setup.
Below is a schematic of my design and the testing configuration using bench-top power supplies.

For the design, I use a 100nF capacitor and a 1Kohm resistor in parallel with the negative input and output of an OP27G op-amp to get the rise-time resolution I want. The photodiode is an FDS100 from Thorlabs.
Questions:
1: Should my 12V line and +15/-15V lines from the power supplies all be constant voltage?
2: Is my design good? Am I missing something?
3: Should I use a different chip than the OP27G?
Thanks for your help/suggestions.

If you assume an ideal opamp (not entirely true), then I believe the (-) lead of the 12 V supply is floating without a galvanic connection. Is that the reality?

The power supplies need to have a common ground, they're floating with respect to one another right now.  The 100nF feedback capacitor also seems unreasonably large.  How did you calculate that value?

The capacitor/resistor values were calculated using the standard photodiode rise time equation: t ~ .35/f(3db) where f=1/(2πRC). My laser operates at 1KHz, so I just need the signal time constant to be ~100us, which is where I came up with R=1kOhm and C=100nF. As to the grounds, how do I connect them to have a common ground?

The photodiode risetime equation refers to the capacitance of the photodiode itself, in this case ~ 24 pF and its series resistance.  In your circuit the photodiode is hooked up to the input of a transimpedance amplifier which is at 0V, so R=0 ohms and that calculation is not going to work.  100 pF might be a more reasonable value to test with, although that'll be faster than you want.

You've defined V- on the first power supply as your "ground", so that has to connect to each of the other rails.  For the -15V supply, put its positive terminal to "ground".  For the +15V supply, put its negative terminal to "ground".  If that doesn't make sense to you, ask your supervisor or instructor for help, learning to use power supplies is important and if you wire things wrong you'll damage your device.

As @user1850479 suggests, you have a ground reference problem. Connect the COM banana of the HP6236B to V- of HP6209 (and to opamp + input). This is your ground reference point.

@glen_geek, ah I see. Thanks for explaining. What is the actual reason for this needing to be the case?

These are both floating DC power supplies. Most certainly you have 30V between HP6236B's V+ and V- terminals. It's COM terminal is always half-way between. If you don't connect COM, there will be an unknown voltage between its V+ and the HP6209's V- terminal. You want op amp's output current to return to COM. The black terminals on both supplies with the "earth" symbol are unrelated to DC output voltage or current. You might connect one to circuit ground if you have sensitive circuits that cannot tolerate an even momentary static surge.

The way you wired it puts 30v across the opamp and 12v across the diode but there is no relationship between the diode and opamp voltage. What you want is the positive 15v above diode ground and minus 15v below diode ground, so you must connect that ground.
